# str_replace work incorrect ("str_replace" makes changes to the $replace parameter)

Tags: php, string, str-replace

Good day!
Specify, for whatever reason, if the number is greater than 10, then `str_replace()` makes changes to the `$replace` parameter, cutting units and leaving only dozens?

Input data (`$data`):

```
...
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=7';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=8';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=9';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=10';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=11';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=12';"></div>
...
```

very simple `PHP` code:

```
for($axx = 0; $axx < 68; $axx ++)
{
    $z = '['.$axx.']';

    $newName = 'templ4-user-'.$z.'.html?'.$z;

    echo '<br>'.$newName; // echo (axx = 13):  <br>templ4-user-[13].html?[13]

    $data = str_replace('template-04.php?type=users&char='.$axx, $newName, $data);
}
```

**Result `$data` incorrect. (`if $axx > 10`) Why?**

```
...
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[7].html?[7]';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[8].html?[8]';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[9].html?[9]';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]0';"></div>   <------ !!!!!!!
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]1';"></div>   <------ !!!!!!! 
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]2';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]3';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]4';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]5';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]6';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]7';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]8';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[1].html?[1]9';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[2].html?[2]0';"></div>
...
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in first iteration all 1's will become [1]'s which means that `12` will become `[1]2` and will never match agains 12 anymore.

Instead of loops, you could use preg_replace :

```
$data = <<<EOS
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=7';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=8';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=9';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=10';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=11';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/template-04.php?type=users&char=12';"></div>
EOS;

$pattern = '/template-04.php\?type=users&char=(\d+)/i';
$replacement = 'templ4-user-[$1].html?[$1]';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $data);
```

Result:

```
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[7].html?[7]';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[8].html?[8]';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[9].html?[9]';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[10].html?[10]';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[11].html?[11]';"></div>
<div onclick="window.location.href='/templ4-user-[12].html?[12]';"></div>
```

Comment: The solution would be to perform the loop in reverse, from 68 to 0.